# Exception handling calculate power

Tags: java, algorithm, error-handling

I've to create a class MyCalculator which consists of a single method long power(int, int). This method takes two integers,  and, as parameters and finds Math.pow(n,p).
- If either n or p is negative, then the method must throw an exception which says "n or p should not be negative.".
- If both n and p are zero, then the method must throw an exception which says "n and p should not be zero."

```
class MyCalculator {
    /*
    * Create the method long power(int, int) here.
    */
    long power(int n, int p) throws Exception {
        if(n==0 && p==0) {
            throw new Exception("n and p should not be zero.");
        } else if(n<0 || p<0) {
            throw new Exception("n or p should not be negative.");
        } else {
            return (long)Math.pow(n, p);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to use Exception handling in a better way in such questions? We have to perform this check in most of the questions. So I need to understand it clearly.

Comment: How does adding a Custom Exception in such cases sound? I know that's a bit extra work, but when is it really worth adding a **Custom Exception**?

Comment: I don't understand why those exceptions are necessary, and how they improve `Math.pow()`. Why should it be an error to raise a negative integer to a positive power?

Comment: I totally agree with you. Actually, the focus here is how to better use Exception Handling in such case scenarios.

Comment: What do you mean by "such case scenarios"? My point is that this scenario doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I can go ahead and remove that negative check condition from the question but maybe that was how it was asked to handle, by not allowing any of the inputs to be negative. 
As I said, the question is not how to improve Math.pow(), there could be anything else in place of Math.pow(), but just to make use of Exception Handling more, this negative condition was taken.

Comment: Answers have already been posted, so don't change the question now. For the future, please keep in mind that Code Review requires real code from a project; general discussions based on hypothetical examples are off-topic.

Comment: If you're making a calculator, negative and zero exponents should be handled. The Math library already handles all cases, so all you need to do is build an interface around those calls. Also your comment is formatted incorrectly and ultimately pointless.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to use Exception handling in a better way in such questions?

What you have is a very good start.

I would suggest refining your exception type where possible. In your case, I would suggest using IllegalArgumentException. Using a specific subtype helps with diagnosing/debugging.

Additionally, since IllegalArgumentException is a type of RuntimeException, you can then remove the `throws Exception` from your method signature.

```
long power(int n, int p) {
    if (n == 0 && p == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n and p should not be zero.");
    } else if (n < 0 || p < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n or p should not be negative.");
    }

    return (long) Math.pow(n, p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your code.

for your request of reusing the checks you have 2 options.

Either one requires that you move the checks into a *parameterized method* first.

Before you can do that you have to understand that the current method is exited immediately when an exception is thrown. This means than you don't need the final `else` :

```
class MyCalculator {
    long power(int n, int p) throws Exception {
        if(n==0 && p==0) {
            throw new Exception("n and p should not be zero.");
        } else if(n<0 || p<0) {
            throw new Exception("n or p should not be negative.");
        } 
        return (long)Math.pow(n, p);
    }
}
```

Now you can select the complete `if/else` and invoke your IDE's *extract method* refactoring (eg. in eclipse press <1> to bring up the quickfix menu and find the refactoring there).

This will change your code to this:

```
class MyCalculator {
    long power(int n, int p) throws Exception {
        verifyOperandsPreconditions(n, p);
        return (long)Math.pow(n, p);
    }
    private void verifyOperandsPreconditions(int n, int p) throws Exception {
        if(n==0 && p==0) {
            throw new Exception("n and p should not be zero.");
        } else if(n<0 || p<0) {
            throw new Exception("n or p should not be negative.");
        } 
    }
}
```

From now on you have 2 was to go:

1. legacy inheritance approach
   In this solution you create a super class with the check method and a subclass that does the actual work:

   This will change your code to this:

   ```
   class MyCalculatorBaseClass {
       // mind the new scope!
       protected void verifyOperandsPreconditions(int n, int p) throws Exception {
           if(n==0 && p==0) {
               throw new Exception("n and p should not be zero.");
           } else if(n<0 || p<0) {
               throw new Exception("n or p should not be negative.");
           } 
       }
   }

   class MyCalculator extends MyCalculatorBaseClass {       
       long power(int n, int p) throws Exception {
           verifyOperandsPreconditions(n, p); // call to base class method
           return (long)Math.pow(n, p);
       }
   }
   ```
2. modern composition approach
   In this solution you use `MyCalculatorBaseClass` as a *dependency* in your `MyCalculator` class:

   ```
    class MyCalculatorChecks {
       // again we change the scope!
       public void verifyOperandsPreconditions(int n, int p) throws Exception {
           if(n==0 && p==0) {
               throw new Exception("n and p should not be zero.");
           } else if(n<0 || p<0) {
               throw new Exception("n or p should not be negative.");
           } 
       }
   }      

   class MyCalculator {   
       MyCalculatorChecks checks = new MyCalculatorChecks();    
       long power(int n, int p) throws Exception {
           checks.verifyOperandsPreconditions(n, p); // call to method on dependency
           return (long)Math.pow(n, p);
       }
   }
   ```

---

About the visibility scopes:

In both example we had to change the visibility scope of the extracted method in order to enable access from other classes.

I choose `protected` in the first approach to signal that this method is meant to be used by sub classes.

I choose `public` in the second approach to signal that this method is meant to be used by any other class.

---

> Which of the two approaches you mentioned is better? "modern composition approach or legacy inheritance approach"    – user2769790

The  "modern composition approach" of cause. Thought my wording was clear enough...

> And do we really need to create a separate class for a single method?  What's a good practice for interview whiteboard preparation? – user2769790

If there is only one method to be shared: Yes.

But most likely you will collect several methods in one object/class.

On the other hand the *Single Responsibility Pattern* must be applied to that common class too which means that you might sometimes need more than one class for such common behavior.

Comment: > Which of the two approaches you mentioned is better?
"modern composition approach or legacy inheritance approach" 

> And do we really need to create a separate class for a single method?

What's a good practice for interview whiteboard preparation?

Comment: (While there *is* "to exact", that probably should read *extracted*: never trust a spelling checker to catch *all* typing errors. And `of cause` still is wrong, of course, as is "the second" `tho`.)

Comment: I downvoted your answer because I think it violates readability, which to me is the most important feature of professional code. In both variants you have to check two classes until you see that the calculator throws an exception in specific cases.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff could you please explain how this affects readability in a bad way?

Comment: Having a method called `extracted` at the end of your answer is unacceptable. It's only acceptable for a tiny moment for explaining how to fix up the method name after doing a refactoring like this.

Comment: @RolandIllig You're right. But did you see that this name comes from the refactoring I introduced earlier in that posting and that I suggested to change that name? I wanted this being easy to follow for the OP and that's why I did not change the name the given by the IDE by default.

Comment: Yes, I saw all that. And I still find that name so ugly that it should be renamed immediately. Otherwise it looks to me as if you didn't know how to name it. And if you didn't know, how should the original poster?

Comment: @RolandIllig fair point. I changed it.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle My point about readability is about the fact that the `power()` method throws an exception in some corner cases. You "hide" that not only in another method, but even in another class. The new name 'verifyOperandsPreconditions()` helps to get an idea that something like that might happen, but is far less explicit than @JvR's version.

Comment: I think refactoring the preconditions check for one specific method into a different class creates an undesirably close coupling between these two classes. The `power()` core implementation relies on the fact that the invalid cases have been checked and handled by throwing an exception. So two methods in two classes have to agree on the decision which cases for `power()` are valid / invalid. To me that's another reason to bring the checks and the implementation as close to each other as possible, preferrably into the same method.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff *"My point about readability ..."* I see your point. But I see a trade off here: the code should not surprise the reader on one hand, but it should focus on the "happy day scenario" on the other hand. In that sense I might have explicitly named the method `throwExceptionWhenpreconditionNotMet()`. But I believe that *verify* is a widely understood shorter equivalent.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff *"I think refactoring the preconditions check for one specific method into a different class creates an undesirably close coupling between these two classes."* Please keep in mind that this is a suggestion for a *novice*. I showed a possibility to solve her problem to avoid code duplication for further `MyCalculator `classes. I thought about introducing *dependency injection* but decided against it to keep this post simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little improvement of in the code extending from JvR's answer: I think it's possible to get rid of the else if since you're throwing exceptions for invalid inputs. I do agree with JvR in using a specific subtypes for exceptions. But I think it's best if you create your own exception extending from IllegalArgumentException like so:

```
public class InvalidCalculatorInputException extends IllegalArgumentException{
    public InvalidCalculatorInputException(String message){
        super(message);         
    }
}
```

Also, I think it's best if you separate the logic for handling the exceptions from the power method. This is to make the power method more readable.
Applying all the things I've mentioned, this is my refactored version of your MyCalculator class:

```
class MyCalculator {
    long power(int base, int exponent) {
        checkIfInputsAreValid(base, exponent);
        return (long) Math.pow(base, exponent);
    }

    private void checkIfInputsAreValid(int base, int exponent){
        if(base ==  0 && exponent == 0)
            throw new InvalidCalculatorInputException("The base and the exponent should not be both 0.");
        if(base < 0 || exponent < 0)
            throw new InvalidCalculatorInputException("Either base or exponent should not be negative. Base is " + base + "; exponent is " + exponent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't find the class InvalidArgumentException in the Java API. Did you mean IllegalArgumentException?

Comment: oh yeah, it's IllegalArgumentException lol. My bad :))

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using custom exceptions coupled with an assertion class.  This would give you a lot of good exception type information to catch and work with, instead of just descriptions in a single exception type.  As well, it cleans up your method nicely by stating in English what is happening.

```
public class MyCalculator
{   
    public long Power(int n, int p) 
    {
        Assert.AreNotZero("n and p", n, p);
        Assert.AreNotNegative("n and p", n, p);

        return (long)Math.Pow(n, p);        
    }   
}

public static class Assert
{
    public static void AreNotZero(string arg, params int[] values)
    {
        if (values.Where(v => v == 0).Any())
            throw new InvalidZeroException(arg);
    }

    public static void AreNotNegative(string arg, params int[] values)
    {
        if (values.Where(v => v < 0).Any())
            throw new InvalidNegativeException(arg);
    }
}

public class InvalidZeroException : Exception
{
    public InvalidZeroException(string argument) : base(argument + " should not be zero") { }
}

public class InvalidNegativeException : Exception
{
    public InvalidNegativeException(string argument) : base(argument + " should not be negative") { }
}
```

Comment: This is about Java, not C#. :)

Comment: @RolandIllig i believe it's about good exception practices and the information is translatable.

Answer (score 0):

If the error handling takes too much space in your code, you can invent a little helper function.

```
private static void ensure(boolean condition, String message) {
    if (!condition) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
    }
}
```

Using this helper method, you can write the `power` function like this:

```
long power(int n, int p) {
    ensure(n != 0 || p != 0, "n and p should not be zero.");
    ensure(n >= 0, "n should not be negative.");
    ensure(p >= 0, "p should not be negative.");
    return (long)Math.pow(n, p);
}
```

Note that the messages are all string literals. If you were to use a string expression like `"n is negative: " + n` instead, this string would be computed on every invocation of `power`, which would make your code very slow. Using string literals, on the other hand, doesn't cost any time.